# Dojo xhrPost Content Encrypted Java Controller Spring

Tags: java, javascript, json, spring-mvc, dojo

I'm using dojo xhrPost. I have a JS object which I convert to json and then send to a Java Controller using xhrPost.  If I console.log the content it's valid JSON.  The Controller class method parameter value looks like it's encrypted or something.

(if there are some syntax errors, apologies, I'm writing this without my IDE but the post reaches the controller etc., there are no console errors, and the json generated in the js file is valid.  The question is : what could be modifying my json on route to the controller?)

.. from my js file

```
var formValues = dijit.byId('form').get('value');
var obj = {};
obj.attr1 = formValues.name;
obj.attr2 = formValues.address;

var objJson = dojo.fromJson(obj);
consol.log(objJson);

var xhrPost = {
      handleAs: "json",
      url : urlAddsVariable, 
      content : { objJson: objJson},
      load: function(response){
        console.error(reponse);
      },
      error: function(error){
        console.error(error);
      }
}
```

console.log >>> {"attr1" : "name", "attr2" = "address value"}

.. java controller

```
@RequestMapping("/add.json")
@ResponseBody
public void add(@RequestParam(objJSon) String json) {

// The objJson string has changed.  The attribute names and values are visible but they are wrapped in characters e.g. S%%%%**attr1**DFSS%%%%**name**FSS  etc.
}
```

Any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you send json, but the method uses POST/request data. If you remove the handleAs:, it will propably work

```
var xhrPost = {
   url : urlAddsVariable, 
   content : { objJson: objJson},
   load: function(response){
     console.error(reponse);
   },
   error: function(error){
     console.error(error);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Although, the dojo.fromJson(obj) converts the js object to JSON which is confirmed from the console.log.   I'll try adding the header you suggested.  I've had this working before no probs so I think there may be some encoding filter declared in the web.xml.  Thanks

Comment: I'll give that a try (tomorrow), although I need to assign the json string a variable that matches the argument in the controller e.g content  : {**argName** : jsonValue}   and the controller              public void add (@RequestParam(**argName**) String value)

Comment: I updated the answer based on you comments (and removed my previous comments, since they where not relevant any more).